# Is there a way to give name to these parameters?

Tags: rust

I have this trait:

```rust
pub trait Player {
    async fn player_create(
        &self,
        input: &PlayerInput,
        lambda: &(dyn Fn(&str, i64) -> Result<Player> + Sync),
    ) -> Result<Player>;
}
```

Is there a way to have this instead? (note the `lambda` `Fn()` named parameters)

```rust
pub trait Player {
    async fn player_create(
        &self,
        input: &PlayerInput,
        // note the `lambda` `Fn()` named parameters
        lambda: &(dyn Fn(team_name: &str, age: i64) -> Result<Player> + Sync),
    ) -> Result<Player>;
}
```

Comment: Pack them into an arguments struct. That aside no, though I question the motivation.